# Use `dput` for POSIXct dates in r: why are they in a format like, e.g., 1070236800 instead of 2003-12-01?

Tags: r, date

I have the following array of `POSIXct` dates

```
>x
[1] "2003-12-01 UTC" "2003-12-02 UTC" "2003-12-03 UTC" "2003-12-04 UTC" "2003-12-05 UTC" "2003-12-08 UTC"

[7] "2003-12-09 UTC" "2003-12-10 UTC" "2003-12-11 UTC" "2003-12-12 UTC"
```

whose structure is:

```
str(x)
 POSIXct[1:10], format: "2003-12-01" "2003-12-02" "2003-12-03" "2003-12-04" "2003-12-05" "2003-12-08" "2003-12-09 ..."
```

Anyway, when I use `dput`, I obtain:

```
structure(c(1070236800, 1070323200, 1070409600, 1070496000, 1070582400, 
1070841600, 1070928000, 1071014400, 1071100800, 1071187200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
```

Comment: Because `POSIXct` is implemented as integers (seconds since origin) with class and  time zone attributes. In the `str` output the `format` tells you that you are not seeing the internal representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POSIXct` is stored as a numeric value representing the number of seconds since midnight on 1st January 1970 UTC. Note that if we write the same `structure` manually with the numeric value set to 0, we get:

```r
structure(0, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
#> [1] "1970-01-01 UTC"
```

We can confirm that POSIXct is stored as a double precision floating point number

```r
x <- Sys.time()

x
#> [1] "2022-11-08 11:33:36 GMT"

class(x)
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

typeof(x)
#> [1] "double"
```

The reason why it is stored as a number is because we need to be able to work on date-times arithmetically. If we subtract numbers from a POSIXct object we are subtracting seconds:

```r
x - 3600
#> [1] "2022-11-08 10:33:36 GMT"
```

If it were stored as a character string, than any time we wanted to perform calculations on date-times or plot them, we would have to parse the character strings into a numerical value, do the calculations, then rewrite the character strings. This is obviously much less efficient than having an underlying numerical representation that uses a special print method to represent the number as a date-time.

Answer (score 2):

`POSIXct` converts date-time with an associated time zone. The number you are seeing i.e. `1070236800` is the number of seconds from 1 January 1970, you'll notice if you have a date before this it will be negative. For example,

```
date <- as.POSIXct("1969-12-31",tz="UTC",format="%Y-%m-%d")
dput(date)
```

Gives

```
structure(-86400, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
```

Since 1969 is before 1970 there is a negative number of seconds and the reason for 86400 is I selected 1 day before 1 January 1970 and there are 86400 seconds in a day

So you'll notice that if I type the seconds from your first element and convert it, it gives the date you initially had

```
as.POSIXct(1070236800, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
```

Yields

```
[1] "2003-12-01 UTC"
```

Storing it this way speeds up computation, processing and conversion to other formats